# JDBC issue reading ande writing Bytes

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3, jdbc-postgres

I am trying to migrate my java application from PostgreSQL 8.4 to latest release.
I am facing an issue with reading the byte data from the db.
I am inserting the IpAddress in bytes in to the table and trying to reconstruct it back in a different process. but while reconstruction i could see and extra '/' character 
here is what exactly i am doing.

```
stat = con.prepareStatement("insert into IPADDR(IP_ADDR, LSVR_ID) values(?, ?)");
InetAddress iaddr = InetAddress.getLoopbackAddress();
            stat.setBytes(1, iaddr.getAddress());
            stat.setInt(2, ID);
            stat.executeUpdate();
```

and read it back like this

```
stat = con.prepareStatement("select IP_ADDR  from IPADDR");
```

when i print the bytes before inserting and after retrieval i could see that they are not same.
for local loopback address which is 127.0.0.1 before inserting its 
"[B@106bdde4"
however the one got from DB looks like [B@6d7eaa83  when i construct string out of it 
it shows additional '/' character ==>"/127.0.0.1"
can anyone please help in resolving this issue

Comment: Why are you using `setBytes` to set the IP address in the prepared statement?

Comment: What is the datatype of the column `ip_addr`?

Comment: code Ipaddress.getaddress() would return bytearray itself. as this is a legacy application Don't have much control over it to change. ip_addr column has a type bytea.